# What is wrong with my method of integrating $\int { 4\sqrt { 36+e^{ x } } dx } $?

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral:

$$\int { 4\sqrt { 36+e^{ x } } dx } $$

What I did:

$$\int { 4\sqrt { 36+e^{ x } } dx } =4\int {\sqrt { 36+e^{ x } } dx } $$

Let $u=36+e^x$, $du=e^xdx$

Now we substitute and get:

$$4\int { \frac { \sqrt { u }  }{ (u-36) } du } $$

Let $v=\sqrt{u}$, $dv=\frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { u }  } du\Rightarrow dv=\frac { 1 }{ 2v }du$

(I think this may be where I made the mistake, although I am not sure why it is wrong).

We substitute once again, and get:

$$4\int { \frac { v }{ v^{ 2 }-36 } dv } =2\int { \frac { 1 }{ v^{ 2 }-36 } dv } $$

We simplify to get:

$$2\int { \frac { 1 }{ v^{ 2 }-36 } dv } =2\int { \frac { 1 }{ (v-6)(v+6) } dv } $$

Now we use partial fraction decomposition to help us integrate this integral:

$$\frac { 1 }{ (v-6)(v+6) } =\frac { A }{ v-6 } +\frac { B }{ v+6 } \Leftrightarrow \frac { 1 }{ (v-6)(v+6) } =\frac { A(v+6)+B(v-6) }{ (v-6)(v+6) } $$

$$1=A(v+6)+B(v-6)$$

Let $v=-6$, then $1=-12B\Rightarrow -\frac { 1 }{ 12 } =B$

Let $v=6$, then $1=12A\Rightarrow \frac{1}{12}$

We substitute our result back in and get:

$$2\int { \frac { 1 }{ 12(v-6) } -\frac { 1 }{ 12(v+6) } dv } =2\int { \frac { 1 }{ 12(v-6) } dv } -2\int { \frac { 1 }{ 12(v+6) } dv } $$

$$\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \int { \frac { 1 }{ (v-6) } dv } -\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \int { \frac { 1 }{ (v+6) } dv } $$

Finally, we evaluate the integral:

$$\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \ln { (|v-6|) } -\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \ln { (|v+6|) } +C$$

$$=\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \ln { (|\sqrt { u } -6|) } -\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \ln { (|\sqrt { u } +6|) } +C$$

$$=\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \ln { (|\sqrt { 36+{ e }^{ x } } -6|) } -\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \ln { (|\sqrt { 36+{ e }^{ x } } +6|) } +C$$

---

Both, Wolfram Alpha and an online integral calculator are giving me different solutions. Did I do something illegal in the step under which I pointed out that I think I may have made made a mistake? 
I would appreciate any guidance/help.

Comment: When you say "we substitute once again",  I think  you divided by $v$ instead of multiplying by $v$.Please check that part again,

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Shouldn't I "divide" by $2v$, since $dv=\frac { 1 }{ 2v }du$ at that point?

Comment: No. You have $du$ in your expression. You have to put $2v dv$ in place of $du$. Instead, you have put $\frac{1}{2v} dv$.

Comment: why is that true? $$4\int { \frac { v }{ v^{ 2 }-36 } dv } =2\int { \frac { 1 }{ v^{ 2 }-36 } dv } $$

Comment: @them, Apparently, it isn't true. I suspected that everything from there on out was done incorrectly since I did not replace $du$, fully. I needed to get $2vdv=du$. Then I would have moved forward in the right direction.

Comment: Seems like the equality should be - $$4\int { \frac { v }{ v^{ 2 }-36 } \mathbf{du} } =  4\int { \frac { v }{ v^{ 2 }-36 } \mathbf{2v dv} } $$

Comment: @them Yes, I got $8\int { \frac { { v }^{ 2 } }{ v^{ 2 }-36 } dv } $ now. I am working on solving the problem from this point now.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I was able to attain the correct solution after accounting for the mistake that you pointed out. Thank you. Please feel free to add the advice/help you gave me as an answer below. I will be sure to accept it and +1.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer  Thank you for your offer. However, my comments are purely suggestions, and they do not warrant the status of an answer. Still, I appreciate your gratitude. Having said that, be careful next time with substitutions!

Comment: When you "substitute once again" what are you substituting? Not V for \sqrt u; you don't have any u to substitute.  In essence you've simply thrown away a 2v.  If you were subbing w for v^2 you get 2v dv = dw s o you'd have $2\int \frac 1 {w-36} dv $.  But that's a lower power in the denom.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int 4\sqrt {36+e^x}dx=|36+e^x=t^2\Rightarrow e^xdx=2tdt\Rightarrow dx=\frac{2tdt}{t^2-36}|=$$
$$=\int 4\cdot t\cdot \frac{2tdt}{t^2-36}=8\int \frac{t^2dt}{t^2-36}=8\int \frac{t^2-36+36}{t^2-36}dt=$$
$$=8\int\left(1+\frac{36}{t^2-36}\right)dt=8\int dt+8\cdot 36\int\frac{dt}{t^2-36}=$$
$$=8t+8\cdot 36\cdot\frac{1}{12}\ln\left|\frac{t-6}{t+6}\right|=8t+24\ln\left|\frac{t-6}{t+6}\right|=$$
$$=8\sqrt{36+e^x}+24\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{36+e^x}-6}{\sqrt{36+e^x}+6}\right|+C$$